# Make laravel localization on big existing project

Tags: laravel, localization

I need to make localization on existing big project. 
I need to add another language, but at all I don’t know from what to begin and to not change every link after adding prefix to the route group.

Maybe somebody can advice me how to create localization on laravel to pretend any mistakes or errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you can use the [Laravel's inbuilt localization system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization). I think you will have to edit every blade view to implement it, which means changing a standard blade view from

```html
<a href="{{ route('homepage') }}">Homepage</a>
```

to

```html
<a href="{{ route('homepage') }}">{{ __('Homepage')</a>
<!-- OR WITH BLADE DIRECTIVE -->
<a href="{{ route('homepage') }}">{{ @lang('Homepage')</a>
```

. Then you would also need to make one file per localization. Well, you will have much more information on the documentation.